# file i/o problem - lines not being written to file as they are being read

Tags: excel, vba, file-io

I have a text file of Things each with some associated parameters like so:

```
1   Thing 1
2   Attribute: X
3   Other1: foo
4   Other2: bar
5   Thing 2
6   Attribute: Y
7   Other1: foo
8   Thing 3
9   Attribute: a
10  Thing 4
11  Attribute: f
12  Thing 5
13  Attribute: m
14  EndText
```

Where the Thing number indicates the attribute position in the following arrays:

```
Current Attribute Array: [X, Y, a, f, m]
Future Attribute Array: [X - 1, Y - 1, a - 1, f - 1, m - 1] ' (representing some mathematical operation based on conditions)
```

(These arrays exist in the code already)

Lets say the above file is called Things.txt. I want to be able to go line-by-line through the file and change "Attribute" from the value in the current array to the operated upon attribute from the future array.

Note that the "OtherN" parameters are there to emphasize that the sections in the file for each "Thing" are not equal in row count.

I have set up a for loop to go from lbound(currentArray) to ubound(currentArray)

Lets say we're on loop iteration 3

I have previously set

```
rowThing = 8 (the row that Thing 3's section begins)
rowNextThing = 10 (the first row that no longer applies to Thing 3)
searchText = "Attribute: a" (a concatenation of "Attribute: " and the 3rd entry in the current attribute array)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

```
Open filePath For Input As #1
Open tempFilePath For Append As #2

    Do While Not EOF(1)

        Line Input #1, textline

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

        ' check the current line to see if it contains the string we're looking 
        ' for (must be in between rowThing and rowNextThing and equal to the 
        ' search text. If so, change whats printed in the tempFile. If not, 
        ' just read from file and write to tempFile
        If (InStr(textline, searchText) > 0 And rowCounter > rowThing And rowCounter < rowNextThing) Then

            Print #2, futureAttribute ' ("Attribute: a - 1", in this case)

        Else

            Print #2, textline

        End If

    Loop

Close #1
Close #2

' delete file, rename tempFile to file (saving the newly written tempFile)
fso.DeleteFile filePath
fso.MoveFile tempFilePath, filePath
```

When I step through the code and reach "Close #2", what I expect to see is a tempFile that looks exactly like the file. Instead I see a tempFile that looks a lot like the beginning of the file, but stops early (only writes up to line 10, for example).

Note that the real file is 888 lines long with 27 different Things.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I was asked to provide a fuller accounting of my code, so here that is

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

rowThing = 0
rowNextThing = 0

' set arrays
currentValueAttributes = Array(9.9, 8.7, 4.5, 4.6, 10.1)
newValueAttributes = Array(9.7, 7.2, 5, 3.5, 7.8)
arrayThings = Array("Thing 1", "Thing 2", "Thing 3", "Thing 4", "Thing 5")

For i = LBound(arrayThings) To UBound(arrayThings) ' this should equate to for i = 0 to 4

    searchTextAttribute = "Attribute: " & currentValueAttributes(i)
    replaceTextAttribute = "Attribute: " & newValueAttributes(i)
    searchTextThing = arrayThings(i)

    If i < UBound(arrayThings) Then

        searchTextNextThing = arrayThings(i + 1)

    Else

        searchTextNextThing = "EndText"

    End If

    Open filePath For Input As #1

        Do While Not EOF(1)

            Line Input #1, textline

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

            ' check the current line to see if it contains arrayThings(i)
            ' if it does, set rowThing as the current line number (saves the rownum of the current Thing)
            If textline Like searchTextThing Then

                rowThing = rowCounter

            End If

        Loop

    Close #1

    rowCounter = 0
    textline = ""

        Open filePath For Input As #1

            Do While Not EOF(1)

            Line Input #1, textline

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

            ' check the current line to see if it contains arrayThings(i + 1) or EndText
            ' if it does, set rowNextThing as the current line number (saves the rownum of the current NextThing)
            If textline Like searchTextNextThing Then

                rowNextThing = rowCounter

            End If

            Loop

        Close #1

        rowCounter = 0
        textline = ""

    Open filePath For Input As #1
    Open tempFilePath For Append As #2

        Do While Not EOF(1)

            Line Input #1, textline

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

            ' check the current line to see if it contains the string we're looking 
            ' for (must be in between rowThing and rowNextThing and equal to the 
            ' search text. If so, change whats printed in the tempFile. If not, 
            ' just read from file and write to tempFile
            If (InStr(textline, searchTextAttribute) > 0 And rowCounter > rowThing And rowCounter < rowNextThing) Then

                Print #2, replaceTextAttribute

            Else

                Print #2, textline

            End If

        Loop

    Close #1
    Close #2

    ' delete file, rename tempFile to file (saving the newly written tempFile)
    fso.DeleteFile filePath
    fso.MoveFile tempFilePath, filePath

Next i
```

Comment: Your question might be easier to follow if you posted the whole code.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have updated the code in my question. I posted the fuller accounting of the code under an EDIT tag.

Comment: Do the lines in the text file have the 1,2,3, etc at the beginning ? I ask because your replaceTextAttributes do not.. Do the things appear in the file in the same order as in Array("Thing 1", "Thing 2", "Thing 3", "Thing 4", "Thing 5") ?

Comment: @CDP1802 no, those are just line numbers.

Comment: What is the answer to my 2nd question.

Comment: @CDP1802 Sorry, yes, the order of everything is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you only need to read your file once, if the aim is to replace the content according to your arrays of values.

I would suggest moving the configuration (thing names, current and new values) onto a worksheet range and using that to drive your code.

Eg: if your range looks like this -

[image]

Then your code can look something like this (untested):

```
Sub TESTER()

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim searchTextAttribute, replaceTextAttribute
    Dim ffI As Integer, ffO As Integer, inThing As Boolean
    Dim rngData As Range, m, filePath, tempFilePath, textline

    Set rngData = Sheet1.Range("A2:C12")

    filePath = "somePath"
    tempFilePath = "otherPath"

    ffI = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Input As #ffI
    ffO = FreeFile
    Open tempFilePath For Append As #ffO

    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline

        m = Application.Match(textline, rngData.Columns(1), 0) '<< is this a Thing?
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'found a Thing, so read the current/new attributes
            searchTextAttribute = "Attribute: " & rngData.Cells(m, 2).Value
            replaceTextAttribute = "Attribute: " & rngData.Cells(m, 3).Value
            inThing = True
        Else
            If inThing And textline = searchTextAttribute Then
                textline = replaceTextAttribute
            End If
        End If
        Print #2, textline
    Loop

    Close #ffI
    Close #ffO

End Sub
```

Comment: So i incorporated the above into my code and had the same issue. My guess is that there must be something wrong some other place in my code, but I'm not sure where.

I appreciate your help @Tim Williams

Comment: OK - not much else to suggest without access to your text file and "thing list"